# libMobileGestalt messages in Xcode Console View when I run apps using Google AdMob Framework, on my real test device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I see the following libMobileGestalt messages in Xcode Console View when I run all my apps using Google AdMob Framework, on my real test device iPhone 6S Plus:

```
Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
Metal API Validation Enabled    
libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 1393 (My_App_Name) does not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and IS NOT appropriately entitled 
libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:550: no access to InverseDeviceID (see <rdar://problem/11744455>)
```

Only in my apps using Google AdMob (GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS versions 7.19.0 and 7.20.0). Only when I use iPhone 6S Plus. Using iPhone 5 test device no any messages in the console.

No messages when I use simulators, all versions.

All apps without Google AdMob don't have any output messages in Xcode using all test devices/simulators.

Xcode 8.3.3, Sierra 10.12.5. 
My devices iOS version is 10.3.2.

No Metal files in my apps.

I see these messages last week. I have never seen them before.

Any ideas?

Whether this would be reason Apple to reject my apps?

Thanks!

Comment: AdMob is using deprecated functionality on iOS and gestalt is warning about its use.   Is there a new version of AdMob available?

Comment: @bbum: 7.20.0 is the last version. I think, from 30 of May, 2017. I use AdMob since 2 yrs and more...

Comment: Downloaded now GoogleMobileAdsSDKiOS 7.21.0.

The same problem..

Comment: Sounds like they need to fix the framework, then.

Comment: Update: using my iPhone 6S Plus test device receive this error message not only in apps using Google AdMobs. The message appears rarely in these apps. The message does not appear right after the start of the app, but I cannot catch any regularity, any reason at all...